# spotify docker/dockerfile maven plugin [ERROR] Copy failed

Tags: docker, docker-maven-plugin, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I am trying to execute the `mvn clean package docker:build` on my project it fails with the following error

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.1.0:build (default-cli) on project
>   mma-access-management-auth-server: Exception caught: COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder181535370/mma-access-management-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
>   no such file or directory -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.1.0:build (default-cli)
>   on project mma-access-management-auth-server: Exception caught
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception caught
>       at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:151)
>       at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:324)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by:
>   com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: COPY failed:
>   stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder181535370/mma-access-management-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:
>   no such file or directory

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mma</groupId>
    <artifactId>mma-access-management-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>mma-access-management-auth-server</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>mma-access-management-rest-api</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>mma/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                    <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
                </imageTags>
                <dockerDirectory>dockerfile</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine
ENV targetDir /usr/local/access-management-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV srcDir .
ENV jarFile mma-access-management-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN mkdir ${targetDir}
COPY ${srcDir}/${jarFile} ${targetDir}
WORKDIR ${targetDir}
CMD ["java", "-jar", "mma-access-management-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
```

I don't know that is going wrong. I also tried to use the dockerfile plugin from spotify which also failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar file of the maven build `${project.build.finalName}.jar` differs from the one you have defined in the `Dockerfile`.

Adjust the specified jar filename in the Dockerfile to match the jar of the maven build and it will work.

```
FROM openjdk:8u131-jdk-alpine
ENV targetDir /usr/local/access-management-auth-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV srcDir .
ENV jarFile mma-access-management-auth-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN mkdir ${targetDir}
COPY ${srcDir}/${jarFile} ${targetDir}
WORKDIR ${targetDir}
CMD ["java", "-jar", "mma-access-management-auth-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like a issue with the spotify plugin. The docker build is failing at 

`COPY ${srcDir}/${jarFile} ${targetDir}`

I guess the `srcDir` points to the `src` folder whereas the jar will be present in the `target` folder.